# mongoose forEach loop and update documents one by one

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to query a collection and update each document using some value that i will get from another query which is gonna be built with some info from the returned document.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userModel = {
      country: { type: String }
      newField: { type: String } 
     };
const myUsersModel = mongoose.model('user',userModel); 
myUsersModel.find({country:"USA"}).forEach(function (doc) {

    // another query here into a relation Database:
    let anotherQuery = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name=' + doc.name;
    mySQLConnection.query(
            anotherQuery,
            function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
                    throw err;
                }
                console.log("Got "+results.length+" Rows:");
                let updatedInfo = results.SomeField;

                // update the mongoose doc:
                doc.newField = updatedInfo;
                myUsersModel.save(doc);

            });
        mySQLConnection.end(function(err) {
          console.log("connection ended.");
        });
        mongoose.connection.close();
    });
```

I am getting the following error:

TypeError: myUsersModel.find(...).forEach is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myUsersModel.find({country:"USA"})
   .then(users=>users.forEach //users might be null here btw
```

Or if you want to keep your callback style

```
myUsersModel.find({country:"USA"}, function(err, users) {
  if (err) throw err;
  users.forEach
```

Comment: cool, but i still get another error, saying that `TypeError: myUsersModel.save is not a function` , how should i save the doc, now?

Comment: @moaningalways use doc.save() http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html

Answer (score 0):

If a callback is not provided, [Model.find](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find)  returns an instance of [Query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) and not an instance of Array. 
Hence, you can not use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as Query is not an Array.

Comment: so what is your solution? could you please give a full answer? thanks

Comment: Looks like Андрей Щербаков has answered it

Comment: thanks however i am having another problem with saving, saying that TypeError: myUsersModel.save is not a function , how should i save the doc?